# Parsing file Excel from PHP

Tags: php, excel

I have a function PHP to parse file Excel, it read all the number of the rows but it doesn't return all the data in the object.
Number of lines 3247, but it return just 1023 lines.

this following  the parsing function:

```
 public function parseEquipement($filePath = null) {    
        set_time_limit(0);
        $listEquipement = [];       
        $count = 0;
        $chunkSize = 8192;
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader(PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($filePath));
        $spreadsheetInfo = $objReader->listWorksheetInfo($filePath);
        $chunkFilter = new \Floose\Parse\ChunkReadFilter();
        $objReader->setReadFilter($chunkFilter);
        $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
        $chunkFilter->setRows(0, 1);
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($filePath);
        $totalRows = $spreadsheetInfo[0]['totalRows'];
        for ($startRow = 1; $startRow <= $totalRows; $startRow += $chunkSize) {
            $chunkFilter->setRows($startRow, $chunkSize);
            $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($filePath);
            $sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, null, true, false);
            $startIndex = ($startRow == 1) ? $startRow : $startRow - 1;         
            if (!empty($sheetData) && $startRow < $totalRows) {
                $dataToAnalyse = array_slice($sheetData, $startIndex, $chunkSize);  
                    if($dataToAnalyse[0][0]==NULL){         
                        break;
                }               
                for ($i = 0; $i < $chunkSize; $i++) {                       
                    if ($dataToAnalyse[$i]['0'] != NULL) {                      
                       $listEquipement[] = new Article($dataToAnalyse[$i]['0'], '', $dataToAnalyse[$i]['1']);                       
                        $count++;

                    }
                }
            } 

        //echo($totalRows); // is best
        //echo($count);  // is wrong
           //print_r($listEquipement);
            $objPHPExcel->disconnectWorksheets();
            unset($objPHPExcel, $sheetData);
        }   

        return $listEquipement;

        }
```

I changed all the code by this following but it doesn't work:

```
public function parseEquipment($filePath = null) {
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader(PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($filePath));
    $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($filePath);
    $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0); 
    $highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
    for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){ 
        echo $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(3, $row)->getCalculatedValue();
        echo $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(4, $row)->getCalculatedValue();
        echo $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2,$row)->getCalculatedValue();
        $listEquipement[] = new Article(
            $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(3, $row)->getCalculatedValue(),
            $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(4, $row)->getCalculatedValue(),
            $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, $row)->getCalculatedValue()
);

    }
}
```

And when I run my code always it display an error of memory size knowing that the size of my file is 81K and it display the number of lines in the same time.

`Fatal Error: Allowed Memory Size of 134217728 Bytes Exhausted (Tried to allocate 54byte`)

Could anyone be kind enough to guide and teach me how I should do my codes or can you suggest me another code to parsing a file Excel ?

Comment: You may want o to check your code for memory leaks or increase the memory on your php script.

Comment: How I can check my code for memory leaks. I tried by incresing memory on my php script but in vein